# AFNetworking replacing - Replace for AFHTTPClient

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I am using the below code below to perform my webservice calls with the service.I used AFNetworking version below 2.0 where AFHTTPClient .Now i migrated to latest version of AFNetworking .I donot find the AFHTTPClient class in the latest version . What should i replace with the curent code so that it works again .Any help please

```
@interface APIClient : AFHTTPClient

+ (APIClient*)client;

- (void)commandWithMethod:(NSString *)method params:(NSMutableDictionary*)params success:(APIClientSuccessCallback)successBlock failure:(APIClientFailureCallback)failureBlock;

@end


// Singleton method
+ (APIClient*)client {

static APIClient *client = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceInst;

dispatch_once(&onceInst, ^{

    client = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APIHost]];

    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                                                       @"application/json",
                                                       @"text/json",
                                                       @"text/javascript",
                                                       @"text/plain",
                                                       @"text/html",
                                                       @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", nil]];
});

return client;
}

#pragma mark - Init

// Intialize the API class with the destination host name
- (APIClient*)init {

self = [super init]; // call super init

if (self != nil) {
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark - Core API Methods

// This function sends an API call to the server
- (void)commandWithMethod:(NSString *)method params:(NSMutableDictionary*)params success:(APIClientSuccessCallback)successBlock failure:(APIClientFailureCallback)failureBlock {

[MBMNetworkActivity pushNetworkActivity];

NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:method parameters:params];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // success! :)
    [MBMNetworkActivity popNetworkActivity];
    successBlock(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // failure! :(
    [MBMNetworkActivity popNetworkActivity];
    failureBlock(error);
}];

[operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSURLSession` for quite a bunch of the `AFHTTPClient` Stuff.
But to achieve all functionality just write a class like you now did but based on NSObject.

`NSURLSession` has a really nice API and great functionality combined with it.

Answer (score 1):

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is the replacement class to subclass instead of AFHTTPClient.  It's not the same but it's probably what your looking for.

I would suggest you read Mattt Thompson's blog NSHipster.  He is the author of AFNetworking and covered the changes a while back http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/.  There is also an AFNetworking 2.0 migration guide https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide that will be usefull to you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to do with following changes replacing AFHttpClient with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

```
typedef void (^APIClientSuccessCallback) (id response);
typedef void (^APIClientFailureCallback) (id error);



@interface APIClient : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager


+ (APIClient*)client;

- (void)commandWithMethod:(NSString *)method params:(NSMutableDictionary*)params success:(APIClientSuccessCallback)successBlock failure:(APIClientFailureCallback)failureBlock;

@end

#import "APIClient.h"

@implementation APIClient


+ (APIClient*)client {

static APIClient *client = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceInst;

dispatch_once(&onceInst, ^{

    client = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APIHost]];
    client.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [client.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

});

return client;
}


#pragma mark - Core API Methods

// This function sends an API call to the server
- (void)commandWithMethod:(NSString *)method params:(NSMutableDictionary*)params success:(APIClientSuccessCallback)successBlock failure:(APIClientFailureCallback)failureBlock {

[self POST:method parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"response --- %@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error ----- %@",error);
}];

}

@end
```

Comment: That's the solution I proposed 23 hours ago